# What did "Propaganda" mean to Germans during WW2?

Tags: nazi-germany, propaganda

The "Reich Ministry of Public Enlightenment and Propaganda" was the primary vehicle that the Nazis had used to enforce Nazi ideology and centralise Nazi control of German culture and thinking.
"Propaganda" literally means "biased information often used to promote a political cause".

It seems strange that the Nazi's had bluntly called this division the "ministry of propaganda" given that  propaganda is a tool that seems to work most effectively when people aren't aware that they are being indoctrinated. Are people not less likely to believe something if they are explicitly told that it has been skewed in order to be convincing and manipulative?

Was the understanding of the concept of "propaganda" different in Nazi Germany?
Did calling it "the ministry of propaganda" have no effect on the way the propaganda was received by the population?

Comment: Related: [Did the German people actually know Joseph Goebbels as the “Minister of Propaganda”?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/11214/did-the-german-people-actually-know-joseph-goebbels-as-the-minister-of-propagan).

Comment: Welcome to History:SE.  Did you look at the Wikipedia article on [Propaganda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propaganda)?  You cite the modern definition, but the etymology shows the word carried fewer negative connotations in the past.

Comment: Propaganda comes from Latin propago (propagate), and original meaning was to disseminate i.e. spread some information. Of course, information coming from "official sources" was often either false of half-truth, especially during wars. Therefore, word propaganda gradually started to symbolize exactly that (lies and half-truths ) . But in interwar period this new meaning didn't fully take hold, otherwise Goebbels (master of propaganda) would select another name for his ministry.

Comment: In Portuguese, "propaganda" still carries the old connotations. It is a common word for advertisement, for instance.